Why is SE Meta so downvotish?
I see many questions on Meta SE that are very interesting to me but many long-time users are so quick to down vote. Why can't Meta SE be more inviting to new members and give real solutions to improve a question, rather then a quick down vote with no explanation? Why not let other novice Meta users have a chance to answer before down voting a question out of existence?
For example these questions:

Don't bump "dead" questions
Why do some comment replies using the @username convention fail to work?
Site Recommendation: Q&A for campers, RVs, camper vans and any Home on Wheels
Are questions asking about a standard way of doing things automatically an opinion based question?

and many others made by new users are relevant but a duplicate, but good questions with good answers, but the hoard down votes... discourages most new users from ever returning.

Most people simply don't understand the purpose of this site. Those that do often ask questions that have been asked before. Either of those situations can lead to downvotes. It's not as if there's some tremendous prize for rep here though.

"Why not let other novice Meta users have a chance to answer before down-voting a question out of existence?" Downvoting doesn't stop you from answering.

Not my fault, it was like this when I found it. Have you read: How to participate in Meta and not die trying.?

@Justintimeforfun ah, and here it is. The most basic and common mistake. Downvote does not mean the one who downvote hate you. I'm sorry you can't understand this very simply fact.

This question is similar to: Does piling up downvotes help the site in any useful way?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

How are you defining "long-time user"? vandench joined Meta.SE 18 months after you did.

Perhaps the height of whimsey I expressed in my comment didn't transfer to the reader. Downvotes are not personal here. See the link in my comment, seriously.

See also: 1. the question/FAQ proposal @W.O. linked above, and 2. Common reasons why your meta post may be negatively received.

Can Ya'll please allow some novice users a chance to answer. Dang. Y'all are just further proving my point.

We're trying to help address a seriously common error of perception of the function and culture of the site. We're friendly, more or less. But this site takes some figuring out.

If a novice user wants to answer the question, they're free to do so. We're not doing anything to prevent that. (Granted, I can't see any close-votes the question may have accumulated, and I'm not sure what kind of answer a "novice user" would be able to contribute anyway, given the nature of the question.)

If you call people hateful then you're not really wanting to engage in reasonable discussion are you?

@W.O. its an observation about how unfriendly this site is compared to others like astronomy, world building, and most others.

Junk questions on Astronomy, Worldbuilding, and all others get downvoted. That doesn't make any of the sites unfriendly - it shows they're at least trying to use the tool appropriately overall. And just like every site on this network, there are standards and expectations here, including that a user will make effort to learn what's acceptable and to check whether a Q&A already exists. None of those users did so, neither did you, that's why those posts and this one get downvoted.

Why is SE Meta so downvote-worthy? PS Are you aware that meta voting includes up/down for agreement/disagreement?

You make lots of bad and wrong assumptions here, and that is the reason I downvoted this specific discussion.
This is what you claim, or at least what is implied for me:
"Long time users downvote all the questions, even the good ones"
And that is simply not correct. On many aspects.

then why not upvote a question and then relate a simular question especially for new users. What harm is in that?

Take a look at this page of questions scrolling to the bottom for a perspective on your handful of downvotes. If you want site culture to change, then you're going to need to do better than "What harm is in that?". @Justintimeforfun

To be fair, it isn't entirely wrong either. MSE is very downvote-happy, to the point that users are scared to post here. This site is supposed to act as a help center and a place where suggestions can be made and it has instead become a place where a small group of core users shut down any new discussions as dupes of things that were discussed a decade ago. Which is exactly how normal SE sites should work, of course, but it does mean that MSE is not fit for purpose as a general help site.

@testing-for-ya yes, I know, I've been a user for more than a decade, and it's been a problem for the same amount of time. As for where it is stated, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic where the first sentence reads "Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) is the primary feedback and discussion space for issues that relate to the sites on the Stack Exchange Network" and the first category listed is "support" to ask for assistance with the site's features. Sadly, MSE has been broken since the moment they split from MSO and got a dedicated rep system, the only meta site to have one.

Oh no, of course those should be downvoted to oblivion, no argument there, @testing-for-ya! But a site that is where users are supposed to come to ask for help with SE or to suggest features etc, cannot function if people are scared of posting here. I have had multiple users tell me they are afraid to come here and, frankly, I get it. I have been on SE for more than 12 years, a mod of between one and three sites for 10 years, and have >25k MSE rep and I still find posting on MSE daunting.

@terdon it always had its own reputation system, even before the split. And it was never meant as "help center" in the sense people can just ask anything.

I admit I don't remember how the rep worked back then, but yes, it's always been broken. And of course it isn't for people to ask anything, I never said it was. It is, however, the place to get help using SE and it fails abysmally at that because of the abrasive nature of the community and fails as a place to suggest things since the rep loss makes people avoid posting things that might be unpopular. And, of course, the nonsense of closing discussion posts as dupes of ancient ones which means no discussion can be revisited.


many long-time users are so quick to downvote

How are you quantifying "long-time user"? (As I noted in a comment, your Meta.SE account is over four years old.) How are you quantifying "so quick to downvote"? How long, for example, do you think a user should have to deliberate for before deciding whether to downvote a question or not? With all due respect, you have no way of knowing how many downvotes on a question were cast by "long-time users", or how "quick" those users may have been to hit the downvote button.

Why can't Meta SE be more inviting to new members and give real solutions to improve a question, rather then a quick downvote with no explanation?

Downvotes work differently on Meta sites. Here, they can simply be used to express disagreement with the premise of a question, rather than to signal that the question needs improvement. The downvotes to this question, for example, likely indicate disagreement with your assertions that users here are "too quick" to downvote questions, or that "most new users" are driven away by downvotes.

Why not let other novice Meta users have a chance to answer before downvoting a question out of existence?

Downvoting a question doesn't prevent people from answering it. Questions do get hidden from the Home tab if they reach a certain score threshold, but a) they're still visible in the Questions tab, and b) that threshold is lower on Meta sites.
I won't deny that high-rep users probably post the majority of answers on Meta.SE, but that's because high-rep users tend to be a) more active here, and therefore more likely to see a particular question, and b) more knowledgeable about Stack Exchange's inner workings, and therefore more capable of answering questions about them (which is what Meta.SE is for).

the [horde of] down votes discourages most new users from ever returning

Again, with all due respect, I think it's too early to make that judgement call in those specific cases, given that those questions were all posted within the last four days. The OP of the first one responded to its answer only an hour ago, and only the OP of the last one has shown any signs of being discouraged as far as I can tell.
I'd also like to note that, even if those users never post to Meta.SE again, that may not necessarily mean they were "chased away" by the downvotes they received on those questions. They may simply have no further questions that need asking. It's not uncommon for users to post to a particular SE site, get the answer they were looking for, then never post there again, not because they don't want to, but because they don't need to.

You answer was thorough. Although I do not agree in down voting a question that has good answers. Novice users should have a fair chance to respond. When I get a down vote seconds after posting a question it seems to me that long time users are gaming this system.

"gaming the system." - if you find you're in a hole, stop digging.

@W.O. This site is inundated with holes. But don't get me wrong, I love the concept of SE but not all of it's facets.

Ha ha. I've fallen in a few, my most recent question received 8 downvotes. @Justintimeforfun I still rely on the place for news, try to help out where I can.

First let's review the criteria for downvoting on the downvote tooltip so we're all on the same page...

This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

In addition this being a meta site, feature-request questions can be voted on as polls.
And now let's take a look at the questions you reference.

Don't bump "dead" questions

That's closed as a duplicate. The question asker didn't reference the duplicate at all so the evidence is they did not show any research effort. It's also a feature-request question so maybe the downvoters simply disagree that this is a good idea, the answer explaining why it isn't certainly has plenty of upvotes to evidence that hypothesis.

Why do some comment replies using the @username convention fail to work?

Basically the same thing. A duplicate with no research effort i.e. evidence of looking at other questions here on this meta for the answer.

Site Recommendation: Q&A for campers, RVs, camper vans and any Home on Wheels

Here we do have evidence of prior research, that should have led the question asker to area 51, or better still to conclude that they need an existing set of interested people to launch a new site successfully. That question has an upvote so the question asker did come out ahead in rep there.

Are questions asking about a standard way of doing things automatically an opinion based question?

Simply too broad a question to work for every possible site. Nobody could answer this in a way that covered every one of our sites and was ultimately useful. Really this question needs to be asked on site metas and in fact it almost certainly has been on those meta sites and has answers pertinent to each individual site.
Apart from the last question the rest are duplicates and if you want to answer them, you still can. You just need to put your answer on the original question in each case. That way we keep all the answers together rather than spreading them across dozens of duplicates.

Too broad so what I bet somebody will and can answer it. Be more forgiving that is what I would like to see. Also, some times these old duplicates need to resurface with a different perspectives as times and opinions change. I just want to see a more welcoming group of long time users inviting interaction and not have users feel their good questions are dumb.

Just interlink the duplicates somehow. Each duplicate may have perceptive that the others do not have.

We do interlink the duplicates via the banner at the top of each duplicate precisely for that reason.

That is only one link to see, I would like to see all of them.

We have that too, go to the originial and look on the right hand side of the page. See the Linked section. That's all the duplicates.
